# Inserting specific information from CSV to SQL python3

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, csv, pymysql

I am having some problems with inserting information from a CSV file to a SQL DB,
This is the code I am using :

```
import csv 
import pymysql    

def sqlinsert(cur, vname, vid, file, db):                                                                 
    insertcsv = '''INSERT INTO `mydb`(VID,name,starttime,stoptime,sessiontime,calledstation,sessionbill)
                VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)'''                                                                                                                                        
    with open(os.path.join(cwd, 'RawCSV', file), 'r') as f:                                               
        reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t')                                                            
        next(reader)    # skipping the first line                                                                                  
        for row in reader:                                                                                
            cur.execute(insertcsv, (vid, vname, row[8:13]))                                                                                                               
            db.commit()
```

The issue is as follows :

```
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
```

If i will remove VID and name from the insert command and do it like this :

```
insertcsv = '''INSERT INTO `mydb (starttime,stoptime,sessiontime,calledstation,sessionbill) VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)'''       
cur.execute(insertcsv, row[8:13])
```

This will import with no issues, What am I missing here?

this is the CSV line :

```
7869574006      1443580239  478 -00000027   1499347553.39   231     2017-07-06
```

Comment: What does the first line of data look like?

Comment: Do you mean for the lines in the CSV?

Comment: That's what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Fix your indentation

2) (vid, vname, row[8:13]) will be a tuple of type (t1, t2, []).
 Where t1 & t2 are the type of vid & vname.

Try to use:

```
row_to_insert = [vid, vname] + row[8:13]    # Appending the two lists.
cur.execute(insertcsv, row_to_insert)
```

Comment: Well that worked, thank you. i assume if i will want to add more rows than i can do something like "
[vid, name] + row[8:13] + row[15:17]"

Comment: No problem, glad I could help! That should do it yes :)